# Tensor product of a right R-module with an (R,S)-bimodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Wikipedia says: if $M$ is a right $R$-module and $N$ is an $(R,S)$-bimodule, then $M\otimes_RN$ is a right $S$-module. What I want to ask are the following two question:

1. How is this tensor product defined? **Is it true that we first forget the right $S$-module structure on $N$, then construct $M\otimes_RN$ as an abelian group, and finally endow it with a right $S$-module structure?**
2. Does this tensor product satisfy any universal property, similar to the one for vector spaces?

---

I propose the following "universal property."

Let $V$ be a right $S$-module, and $f:M\times N\to V$ be an $R$-middle-balanced map that is right $S$-linear in the second variable, there is a unique morphism of right $S$-modules $\bar f:M\otimes_RN\to V$ such that
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
M\times N & \stackrel{\otimes}{\longrightarrow} & M\otimes_RN
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& f{\Large\searrow} & ~~~{\Large\downarrow}~ \bar f
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
& & V
\end{array}
$$
commutes.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 

If you have a right $R$-module $M$ and a left $R$-module $N$, then you can define an abelian group $M \otimes_R N$ in exactly the way you expect. It's generated by pairs $m \otimes n$ subject to the constraints

- $(m_1 + m_2) \otimes n = m_1 \otimes n + m_2 \otimes n$
- $m \otimes (n_1 + n_2) = m \otimes n_1 + m \otimes n_2$
- $mr \otimes n = m \otimes rn$

where in the third bullet we remember that $M$ is a *right* $R$-module and $N$ is a *left* $R$-module.

Now if $N$ is an $(R,S)$-bimodule (that is, both a left $R$-module and a right $S$-module), then of course we can forget about the $S$-module structure and take the tensor product $M \otimes_R N$, as you've guessed. Also as you've guessed, we can use the (right) $S$-module structure on $N$ to put a (right) $S$-module structure on $M \otimes_R N$! We define

$$(m \otimes n) s = m \otimes (ns)$$

One can check that everything here is well defined, but I'll leave those details to you.

---

2. 

Yes, this tensor product satisfies a universal property. First, as is mentioned on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules) for tensor products, given a right $R$-module $M$ and a left $R$-module $N$, the tensor product $M \otimes_R N$ is the universal module with an "$R$-balanced map" from $M$ and $N$. Here an "$R$-balanced map" $f : M \times N \to A$ is a bilinear map to an abelian group $A$ with the ~bonus property~ that $f(mr,n) = f(m,rn)$.

In case $N$ is an $(R,S)$-bimodule, we have the same universal property. It just happens to be that one can show the representing object is also an $S$-module. This does have some interesting categorical content behind it, though! See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535539/module-structure-on-the-tensor-product-universally) for more.

*However* in the special case that $N = S$, there *is* a nice universal property! In this case $S$ is a (left) $R$-algebra and there's a forgetful functor from $\mathsf{Mod}_S \to \mathsf{Mod}_R$ taking an $S$-module $M$ and viewing it as an $R$-module by defining $mr = m(r 1_S)$. This uses first the $R$-action on $S$ to get an element $r 1_S$, and then the $S$-action on $M$ to multiply $m$ by $(r 1_S)$!

In the special case $R = \mathbb{R}$ and $S = \mathbb{C}$, then this is saying that we can view a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space by defining $vr$ to be $v(r1_\mathbb{C})$, which is of course $vr$ where we view $r$ as a complex number, since $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$!

You might ask if this forgetful functor $\mathsf{Mod}_S \to \mathsf{Mod}_R$ has a left adjoint. That is, if there's a way to freely "extend" an $R$-module $M$ to an $S$-module. So in our example, if there's a way to freely extend a real vector space to a complex vector space. It turns out the answer is *yes*, and we do it by tensoring with $S$! You already know that $S$ is a $(R,S)$-bimodule, so $-\otimes_R S$ is a functor $\mathsf{Mod}_R \to \mathsf{Mod}_S$. The incredibly useful fact is that it's left adjoint to the forgetful functor we described earlier! If you want to read more about this, the key word to google is [extension of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings). You can also find a worked out proof of this adjunction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595388/restriction-of-scalars-is-a-right-adjoint-to-tensor-product).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Could you provide an explicit statement of the universal property satisfied by $M\otimes_RN$ as a right $S$-module? I would expect something like "for every right $S$-module $V$, and for every $R$-balanced and $S$-linear map, we have ... such that ... commutes", but this could be wrong.

Comment: I editted the question and proposed a universal property. Would it be correct?

Comment: @Zhuo -- If you reread my answer, I said there _isn't_ a special universal property for $M \otimes_R N$ as an $S$-module. Instead, the "universal object with an $R$-balanced map", which a priori should only be an abelian group, happens to also be an $S$-module! You can read more about why you get an $S$-module in Qiaochu's excellent answer that I linked

Comment: And yes -- the universal property you mentioned in your question should work ^_^